# Can I setup heroku environment variables with CLI?

Tags: heroku

I want to change the environment variable to start the app in production mode. Is it possible to do it in console with the client toolkit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible as explained [here in the docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#setting-up-config-vars-for-a-deployed-application)

`heroku config:set NAME=VALUE`